# Can I run two external monitors on Dell Inspiron 15RMT-7567

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

My laptop has only HDMI and USB ports (one is USB 3) but no VGA port.  I want to run two 23" external monitors and don't care about using Laptop display.  How can I do this the best way if I can do it at all. I think there are some splitters and such but not sure what would be best.  I am not doing any graphic intensive things but rather mostly Excel, powerpoint, etc.

any help would be great.

Comment: You can get docking stations that have all the connections (including things like dual DVI or dual HDMI, ethernet, USB3 etc.) That plug in to one single USB3 port on your laptop. E.g. http://www.notebookcheck.net/USB-Docking-Station-in-Review-Lenovo-USB-3-0-Dock-0A33970.81021.0.html

Comment: The problem with "splitters" are they do just that. They don't allow you to use both displays independently - which is the important factor here. As your laptop only has a single HDMI you'll only ever be able to connect a single HDMI monitor do you need to use a mechanism that brings two screen capability. It's basically a new graphics card bit USB3 bandwidth gives us this capability nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, when it comes to laptops, you are restricted to the amount of Video Connections built into the laptops board in order to add additional monitors, or use a Laptop Docking Station

If you checkout the certified accessories for your branded laptop, you will find the following Docking Station which will allow you to use both DVI and HDMI expansion slots for dual monitors:

http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?sku=332-0446&ref=meekosystems

You can also search around for other docking stations that will fit your needs, just be sure to make sure it is compatible with your system.

Comment: Link is broken and I can't find an alternative :-(

Comment: You can do a search for the following in google - Dell SuperSpeed USB 3.0 Docking Station (YWDN0) - I also tested that link and it is working.

Comment: Strange, I am still getting a "Our apologies... The page you requested cannot be displayed." Maybe Dell is doing maintenance. But you answer is not just a link and helped me.